# ValueError: Expected more than 1 value per channel when training in pytorch 1.8

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, normalization

The input tensor size is `[1, 512]` and I feed it in a `GroupNorm` layer.

The layer is `self.fc_bn1 = nn.GroupNorm(512 // reduction, 512 // reduction)` and the input is `x = self.fc_bn1(x)`

The error is visible in this image:

[image: error message]

That will be worked when I run it in pytorch 1.1, but now I got a machine with pytorch 1.8 and it doesn't work. Since GPUs in this machine cannot use pytorch 1.1, I want to know how to solve this.

I already set `model.eval()`, so I guess it's not this reason.

Comment: From the error message, I can only guess you used a batch size of 1, and due to the `groupNorm` layers of your model, this is not something valid. You could try to increase the batch size

Comment: Thanks for your conment! I did use a batch size of one. It is wried that the exactly same code can work on pytorch 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does work in pytorch1.1. But I think this is a bug, because the output after GroupNorm is all 0, which is consistent with the mathematical formula. In subsequent versions, this bug has been fixed, so an error is reported.